# Not getting any permission in API 23 android

Tags: android

I am trying to get the location lat and long using Location Manager in android, for API level 23 i am asking permission for GPS enabled, and it's woking fine till that.
After getting permission it's not going to the MainActivity.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen_main);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 ){
            requestMultiplePermissions();
        }


        final Thread splashScreenThread = new Thread() {

    public void run() {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);

        } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            Intent homeScreen = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);

        }
    }
};

        splashScreenThread.start();
    }

    //Marshmallow permission code
    private void requestMultiplePermissions() {
        String locationPermission = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
        int hasLocPermission = checkSelfPermission(locationPermission);
        List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (hasLocPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            permissions.add(locationPermission);
        }

        if (!permissions.isEmpty()) {
            String[] params = permissions.toArray(new String[permissions.size()]);
            requestPermissions(params, 1);
        } else {
            // We already have permission, so handle as normal
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult ( int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                             int[] grantResults){
        Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this," "+grantResults,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // Handle permission granted
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this , MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                } else {
                    // Handle permission denied
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                            .setMessage("The app cannot continue without permissions")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    SplashScreen.this.finish();
                                }
                            })
                            .show();


                }
                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
        //

    }
}
```

Help as it is my first time.

Comment: Please upload the code of your build.gradle file in main folder

Comment: Can you tell me what is the problem, why my intent is not working.

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/10-good-rules-for-bad-app-part-1-technical-4ca18609b13c#.tmuvppy8x post #1 is for you

Answer (score 0):

In your **else** condition inside `requestMultiplePermission`, start your activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this , MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Could you add logs into all your conditions and check which one is triggered?